# How to evaluate non existing value to null in Symfony Expression Language

Tags: symfony

Is there any way to evaluate non existing value to null so it can be used in boolean expressions?

Something like:

```
$expressionLanguage = new ExpressionLanguage();
var_dump($expressionLanguage->evaluate(
    '!noVar',
    [
        'existingVar' => 'foo',
    ]
)); // displays 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no such a feature in the Symfony Expression Language.

We ended up by creating extension to it and we published it on github.

- GitHub repository with the extension: https://github.com/zef-dev/zef-expression-language
- Symfony issue that describes desired functionality: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21691